Difference in debug and regular Java serialization in VS Code
I'm serializing and deserializing a large sequence of arrays in Java.
All I previously had to do was add implements Serializable to my classes and it all worked.
Now, when I try to run the same code that I could debug before, I get a series of errors:

java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: serialVersionUID

and if I add that field

java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: serialPersistentFields

etc.
Running the same code in non-debug mode in VS code works fine.  The code worked in debug until very recently.  Rolling back to an earlier version doesn't change the problem, even though it worked on that previous version.
The data fields in the class I'm serializing are:
private int n;
IntSet a;
private int b = 0;
private int c;
Set<String> f = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>();
Set<Integer> e = new HashSet<Integer>();

where IntSet has fields of
private int[] x = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2 + 2];
private int[] y = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2 + 2];
private int[] z = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2 + 2];
private int[] w = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2 + 2];

Any ideas what I'm missing?  I'm assuming it's a setting in VS Code, but I'm not sure what.

@MarcePuente I can't post the code. And I reckon producing a small example that exhibits the problem... probably won't exhibit the problem. As I said, my code didn't exhibit the problem until a few hours ago.  I'll add some of the other things you suggest to see if that helps.

work with threads?.

@MarcePuente Eventually, but the code is bombing out before that part of the operation happens. It just never allows loading the serialized object from disk.

You may try disable all exception breakpoint in debug mode and see if the issue disappears.
